# Updating an old version of Ubuntu on an armhf port to a more modern version

Tags: upgrade, arm

I'm currently messing with a [orangepi R1](http://www.orangepi.org/OrangePiR1/) - it's an arm hf board that the developer has supplied an image for. It's allegedly Ubuntu server but 15.04 (I have my doubts that it's an actual Ubuntu server build since there's a ton of lxde packages floating around), and I'd like to get it up to a modern version of Ubuntu.

If it was x86, I could set up the [old version repos](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release), and do a release update through the versions or do a fresh install. There's no old releases repo for http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ - which is what this uses.

Is there any  way to get this up to a modern LTS version of Ubuntu?

Comment: Just use old-releases.ubuntu.com I think it has the armhf packages on there too.  But you may want to consider just a straight reinstall... not sure if the UBports project supports old boards though

Comment: Not as far as I can tell on both. I'd love to do a straight reinstall but, well, doing that is probably another AU question

Comment: you sure about that?  I see armhf stuff in http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ in the packages pool... not sure if 15.04/15.10 is still kept around though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its been a while but - as one can tell from my question, it ended up being a horribly hacked together mismash of different builds. Essentially there's no way to get the original/official orange pi image up to date.

There was no official release but the [armbian build of Ubuntu](https://www.armbian.com/orange-pi-r1/) worked fine.

From there things worked as they should have